# DataGridView Default Error Dialog. System.FormatExeption: Formated value of the cell has a wrong type

Tags: datagridview, datagridviewimagecolumn

I've got an Addin with two(2) DataGridViews(DGV1 and DGV2).
DGV1 is horizontally based representing data from CAD files within a certain folder.
In DGV1, each file has it's own row with different columns to show data, nothing special, just what you've expected.
DGV2 is acting like a horizontal ribbon to show also a picture from the CAD model, each file here has it's own column with four(4) rows to show data.
In the program, 1st DGV1 is filled with data an sorted on a specific column.
Next I iterate trough the rows of DGV1 to fill DGV2.
I create a DataGridViewImageColumn in DGV2 and next I create four(4) rows if they not already exist, something like:

```
Private Sub CreateImageColumnForDataGridView2()
        DataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        DataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = False

        Dim ColImage As New DataGridViewImageColumn
        DataGridView2.Columns.Add(ColImage)
        ColImage.Width = MainPictureWidth '150
        If DataGridView2.RowCount = 0 Then
            DataGridView2.Rows.Add(1)
        End If
        If DataGridView2.RowCount = 1 Then
            DataGridView2.Rows.Add(3)
        End If
End Sub
```

In this DataGridViewImageColumn row 1 and 4 are displaying a string while row 2 and 3 are displaying an image.
To show a string in the DataGridViewImageColumn I use:

```
DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(DataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1) = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
```

Every 1st time I run the Addin everything seems to go right, but when I reload the folder, or load another folder, I get an 'DataGridView Default Error Dialog' on the command line mentioned above like: 
System.FormatExeption: Formated value of the cell has a wrong type.

The  'DataGridView Default Error Dialog' suggest: To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.

That's what I did to continue the Addin running but I like to know what is actually going wrong , why I'm getting this error?

Before adding the DataGridViewImageColumn I already, each time, cleared al columns and rows.

Anyone an idea what is going wrong here?

I found a post where this is discussed ending with the suggesting using the DataError event, which I did.

Please notice that the error appears even before the string-value is given to the cell.
Telling the program that the cell must be seen as an TextBox-cell seems enough to trigger the error, why?

Thanks for reading, any suggestions are welcome.

Greetings!

Comment: What do you think the statements: `DataGridView2.Rows.Add(1)` and `DataGridView2.Rows.Add(3)` are doing? The first statement will add one (1) row and place a “1” in the first column cell. The second statement will add one (1) row and place a “3” in the first column cell. Is this what you are expecting? The error clearly indicates that you are trying to add an invalid item to a cell in the grid. Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: Thanks John for your reaction. I know these statements are overdone, it's the result of trying to get rid of the error. I want to end with a total number of four(4) rows. What's the best method to create four(4) rows if there are no rows already in your opinion? I thought the number between the brackets is the number of rows who are created, am I wrong?

Comment: The error occurs in:    DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(DataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1) = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell